# How to prove this inequation

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose functions $$f(t),g(t),h(t)$$are defined on$(0,+\infty)$,satisfying:

(1)$f(t),g(t),h(t)$ are positive and real-valued;

(2)$g(t)\le f(t)+\int_0^tg(s)h(s)ds,t\ge0$;

(3)$f'(t)\ge0$;

(4)$\int_{0}{^\infty}h(t)dt=A\lt\infty$.

How to prove: $g(t)\le e^Af(t)$?